# Using foreach on Linked List in C#. Only the last element gets printed

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am writing the following code and want to traverse through the linked list but only the last object's properties get printed when I try to print. But I cannot figure out the reason for it.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

        tempPet.Name = textBox1.Text;
        tempPet.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        tempPet.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        tempPet.Height = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        pets.AddLast(tempPet);
        //Reset the fields.
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Pet Added");
        foreach (Pet p in pets)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" " + p.Age);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not redeclaring `tempPet` anywhere, and I'm going to assume it's a `class`. Therefore you're presumably just changing the same `tempPet` over and over and over again, rather than creating a new one each time. Would you say that's a correct assessment of the situation?

Comment: @Llama Thanks that worked. I was updating the same object through reference. And yes the question is a duplicate. Do I need to remove it or take any other action?

Comment: No, you don't have to. There's the concept on [so] of "signpost questions", which basically provides another point through which someone using a search engine might find the solution they're looking for. If you leave your question, it will essentially be a signpost question.

Answer (score 0):

However you have shown the incomplete code, what I think is you are having **pets** as a **local variable** inside function and not **global variable**.
So what you need to do is either create a global variable named pets or pass the previous pets argument into the function parameters.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
        tempPet =new YOUROBJECT();

        tempPet.Name = textBox1.Text;
        tempPet.Age = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        tempPet.Weight = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        tempPet.Height = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        pets.AddLast(tempPet);
        //Reset the fields.
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
        MessageBox.Show("Pet Added");
        foreach (Pet p in pets)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" " + p.Age);
        }
    }
```